# Swift Equatable Generic type comparison inside generic function

Tags: swift, generics, equatable

I have a `Node` class for a binary tree like so:

```
class Node<T: Equatable> {
    let value: T
    let left: Node<T>?
    let right: Node<T>?

    init(value: T, left: Node<T>? = nil, right: Node<T>? = nil) {
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    }
}
```

The values need to be equatable.

I can test out the equitability like this:

```
let a = Node(value: 8)
let b = Node(value: 7)

let c = a.value > b.value
```

Which works fine, `c: true`

But when I write a generic function that uses the equitability of the nodes I get errors:

```
func isBinaryTree<T>(node: Node<T>) -> Bool {
    if let leftNode = node.left {
        guard leftNode.value < node.value else {
            return false
        }
        guard isBinaryTree(node: leftNode) else {
            return false
        }
    }
    if let rightNode = node.right {
        guard rightNode.value >= node.value else {
            return false
        }
        guard isBinaryTree(node: rightNode) else {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

let result = isBinaryTree(node: root)
```

Errors:

```
error: binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands guard leftNode.value < node.value ||`
```

I'm not sure why the compiler doesn't seem to know why the `T` values are `Equatable` or why it doesn't think that the `T` on the `leftNode` is the same type as the `T` on the `node`.

The code:

```
let d = Node(value: Float(3), left: Node(value: Int(8)) , right: nil)
```

Gives an error as expected.

Looking further into this, it isn't related to the function because when I try the code:

```
let x = Node(value: 3, left: Node(value: 8) , right: nil)
let y = x.value < x.left!.value
```

I get the same error

Comment: Your example `c` can't be possible, because your `Node` isn't `Comparable`.

Comment: I feel really silly having mixed up my `Equatable` and `Comparable`. Thank you!

Comment: What you actually need is the `Comparable` protocol. The `Equatable` protocol only needs the implementation of the equality (`==`) function for conformance. The comparison functions (such as `<`) are only guaranteed to be implemented by the `Comparable` protocol.

Comment: @richy In an arbitrary tree like this, it doesn't really make sense for it to be comparable. You should just access the `value` and compare those

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the general case, two `Node` objects aren't comparable. It depends on the kind of tree they're found in. It would make sense, for example, if nodes were only constrained to be valid members of a binary tree, but this isn't the case.

Luckily, you don't need `Node` to be `Comparable`, you can just need for its `value` to be `Comparable`:

```
class Node<T: Comparable> {
    let value: T
    let left: Node<T>?
    let right: Node<T>?

    init(value: T, left: Node<T>? = nil, right: Node<T>? = nil) {
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    }
}

extension Node: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
            && lhs.left == rhs.left
            && lhs.right == rhs.right
    }
}

extension Node {
    func isBinarySubTree() -> Bool {
        return left.map { $0.value < self.value } ?? true
            && right.map { self.value < $0.value } ?? true
            && left?.isBinaryTree() ?? true
            && right?.isBinaryTree() ?? true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alexander, I had my `Equatable` and `Comparable` mixed up! the Node should be

```
class Node<T: Comparable> {
    //...
}
```

the code:

```
let a = Node(value: 8)
let b = Node(value: 7)

let c = a.value > b.value
```

Must be working because the compiler knows the values are `Int`s. But in the function, the input values aren't known.